# Why is dynamic importing of dayjs not working in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollupjs

I am working on a web screen inside a .NET app and I am trying to send date time preference from the system to the web screen using CefSharp settings and setting

```
AcceptLanguageList = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name
```

In my typescript code I want to use dayjs and import dynamically 'dayjs/locale/${language}' where language comes from AcceptLanguageList above.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import localeData from 'dayjs/plugin/localeData';

dayjs.extend(localeData);
var lang = navigator.languages != null ? navigator.languages[0] : navigator.language;
lang = lang.toLowerCase();
import(`dayjs/locale/${lang}`).then(
        () => {
            dayjs.locale(lang);
            setAdapterLocale(lang);
        });
```

The thing is, when I run this code in browser and try to import 'dayjs/locale/fr-ca', for example, it works fine, but when 'fr-ca' comes from CefSharp, then the import fails with

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> 'dayjs/locale/fr-ca'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's probable that your module specification (`dayjs/locale/...`) has to start with `./`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a dynamic path for the dynamic import then you'll first have to list all of the possible paths that you will potentially want to have, otherwise your bundler wont know which files to include.

You can add `import('dayjs/locale/fr-ca')` anywhere in your code and the bundler will include it when it builds your app for the browser.

And you'll still going to get that error if you don't have a locale for user's language, so you should catch that case:

```js
import(`dayjs/locale/${lang}`).then(
        () => {
            dayjs.locale(lang);
            setAdapterLocale(lang);
        },
        () => { // in case the import fails
            // maybe default to english
            dayjs.locale('en');
            setAdapterLocale('en');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that when building the package for the .net app, the package was created using rollup (which is not the case when running in browser).
Rollup needs some special config to support dynamic import:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).